# Query two databases without models sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two databases, usersDB and analyticsDB. I am using node.js and I have connected both databases to the node app. Now, I want to query each database using raw SQL queries **without setting up a model**. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to establish two different connections for both databases, then use the raw queries.

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

// For example, use Postgres as database
const usersDbConnection = new Sequelize('postgres://user:password@host:port/usersDB');
const analyticsDbConnection = new Sequelize('postgres://user:password@host:port/analyticsDB');

usersDbConnection.query(`select * from "USERS_TABLE_NAME"`).then(res => {
  const users = res[0];
  console.log(users);
});

analyticsDbConnection.query(`select * from "ANALYTICS_TABLE_NAME"`).then(res => {
  const analytics = res[0];
  console.log(analytics);
});
```